# Thermal time constant, thermal resistance, thermal capacitance

Tags: power-supply, power, cables

Where does the thermal time constant, thermal resistance and thermal capacitance in IEC standard 60853-2 come from (e.g. section 4.1.4)?

They are used to determine the partial transient of a cable.

I understand that the thermal time constant may be provided by the cable producer. It can also be estimated. Where is this estimation described? Is it in some IEC standard? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the computation of some of the required values is explained in iec 60287-2-1.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://siemens.siprotec.de/download_neu/applications/SIPROTEC/english/Appl_07_Thermal_Overload_Protection_en.pdf) document talks about how to estimate the time constant from the allowed short-circuit current (for a certain period of time) and the allowed continuous current.
You find these equations on page 3:

[image: relevant clip from pdf document]

Comment: Thanks I came accross this document. However, to determine the continous current rating (see IEC 60287-1-1 - e.g. section 1.4.1.1) one needs the thermal resistance of the cable, which I am also looking for. This makes it a bit of a catch 22 situation.

Comment: @csetzkorn: I see. Unfortunately I do not have a convenient access to the IEC document. I guesss in order to estimate the thermal resistance you can't just take the thermal resistance of the insulation material and its thickness, as the cable is a cylindrical object.